# Combine array base on category, designer and brand and divide array base on category, brand , designer

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 PHP arrays, the first of which stores values, and the second of which stores keys, like so:

1. `['first designer', 'shirt', 'cloth1', 'cloth2', 'second designer']`
2. `['designer', 'brand', 'category', 'category', 'designer']`

I'd like to transform these arrays so that I can output them in the following format, grouping items in the first array based on the respective element of the second array:

```
  <div id="category">
  cloth1
  cloth2
  </div>

  <div id="brand">
  shirt
  </div>

  <div id="designer">
  first designer
  second desinger
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $foo = array("designer", "brand", "category", "category", "designer");
    $bar = array("first designer", "shirt", "cloth1", "cloth2", "second designer");
    $baz = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($foo); $i++) {
        $baz[$foo[$i]][] = $bar[$i];
    }

    foreach ($baz as $key=>$values) {
        echo '<div id="' . $key . '">
';
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            echo '    ' . $value . '<br />
';
        }
        echo '</div>
';
    }
?>
```

This will output:

```
<div id="designer">
    first designer<br />
    second designer<br />
</div>
<div id="brand">
    shirt<br />
</div>
<div id="category">
    cloth1<br />
    cloth2<br />
</div>
```

**Codepad**: http://codepad.org/T7NmPyVR